# What language is this code snippet written in / what does it do?

Tags: c++, delphi, discrete-mathematics

One of my professors in my discrete mathematics class used this code trying to explain number sets and such, but I don't have any idea what it actually does. My guess is it's Delphi or something similar? Can someone please explain (especially `M[r,k] := M[r,k] or M[c,k]`) or maybe write the same thing but in C++ maybe?

```
for c := 1 to n do
  for r := 1 to n do
    if M[r,c] then
      for k := 1 to n do
        M[r,k] := M[r,k] or M[c,k]
```

Comment: in c `for (int c=0; c<n; c++) for (int r=0; r<n; r++) if (M[r][c]) for (int k=0; k<n; k++) M[r][k] = M[r][k] || M[c][k];`

Comment: Yes, this is some variant of Pascal language. However, this is kind of question you need to ask your professor. Also, it is lacking full declaration of the M variable. We can guess that this is array of booleans, but it also might be some integer type and there is slight difference between what code does in former and later case.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like "Pascal" programming language.

it takes a 'n' size square matrix filled with booleans.
Checks every value in it.

If the boolean on row 'r' and column 'c' is true, Applies "or" operation on each element of row 'r' with each element of row 'c' respectively, stores the result on row 'r'.

for exemple. random matrix with 'n' = 3

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| r2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| r3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

has M[1,3] and M[3,2] being true
Those operations will occur:

```
//as M[1,3] is true
M[1,1] := M[1,1] or M[3,1];
M[1,2] := M[1,2] or M[3,2]; 
M[1,3] := M[1,3] or M[3,3];

//as M[3,2] is true
M[3,1] := M[3,1] or M[2,1];
M[3,2] := M[3,2] or M[2,2]; 
M[3,3] := M[3,3] or M[2,3];
```

so the matrix will become.

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| r2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| r3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Hope this helps.

in c it will look like (Careful, in c arrays are 0 based).

```
//bool M[n][n];

for (int r=0;r<n;r++){
  for (int c=0;c<n;c++){
    if (M[r][c]) {
      for (int k=0;k<n;k++){
        M[r][k] = M[r][k] || M[c][k];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that in Pascal, fixed size arrays can be defined with non-zero based index, so M would probably be `var M: Array[1..n, 1..n] of Boolean;`, hence the use of `1 to  n` in the for loops

Comment: @GerryColl You are right. Edited to warn about that on C code.